# Утворення відносного прикметника від слова "комікс"

Tags: правопис, прикметники

Чи правильно буде утворити відносний прикметник від слова **комікс** за допомогою суфікса *-н-*: **коміксний**?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko Comic і comics - абсолютно різні слова. Не вводьте людей в оману і, будь ласка, припиніть стверджувати щось про те, про що не маєте жодного уявлення. Я вже не раз за вами спостерігав, що ви говорите про речі про які не маєте жодного уявлення і хтось, але може подумати, що ви маєте рацію серед того, що ви написали.

Comment: Слово сomics походить від слова comic, ось що мається в словниках під множиною, проте має АБСОЛЮТНО інше значення, яке ніяким чином не перетинається зі словом comic. Крім того, comics не відмінюється, це стале слово як mathematics, thermodynamics і т.д., таким чином це ще і однина, і множина водночас. Це знають всі люди, котрі знають англійську, без образ, але ви її не знаєте, проте часто вважаєте, що знаєте і можете робити авторитетні ствердження. Якщо не впевнені на 100% в чомусь - будь ласка, не пишіть це.

Comment: Вважаю, що це слово "comics" можна перекласти, а отже подібного прикметника не повинно існувати.

Comment: @improbable "Слово сomics походить від слова comic, ось що мається в словниках під множиною, проте має АБСОЛЮТНО інше значення, яке ніяким чином не перетинається зі словом comic." - проблема в тому, що слово comics - це множина від слова comic, а отже воно має схоже значення, але в множині. Інша справа, що слово comic в множині використовують для певного випадку для опису журналу. Слово не змінює свого значення, просто ви його не розумієте. Воно може впливати на зміст.

Answer (score 3):

У [«ГРАК»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[word%3D"%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81.*"+%26+tag%3D".*adj.*"+]) я бачу 16 траплянь *коміксовий*, 1 трапляння *коміксоподібний* і жодного трапляння *коміксний*/*коміксичний*/*коміксуватий*/тощо. Отже ***коміксовий***. (*Коміксний*, можливо, і не порушує традицій словотворення, але на практиці вживається значно рідше.)

Answer (score 3):

[Боксовий](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9), [коксовий](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9), [барсовий](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9).

> **БО́КСОВИЙ**
>   Прикм. до бокс.
>   * Безприв’язне утримання корів може бути боксовим, на щілинній підлозі або на глибокій незмінюваній підстилці. (*з наук. літ.*)
>   * На цьому місці, у 80 метрах від обеліска Слави, спорудили залізобетонний приватний боксовий гараж із в’їздом і виїздом на Дніпровський узвіз. (*з газ.*)
>   * Комплект поставки боксовий.

Якщо йти за аналогією, то **коміксовий**.